# i don't understand this - TypeError: can't multiplysequence by non-int type of float

Tags: python, typeerror

i'm trying to do spatial lag with a dataset but i don't understand what i need to change to satisfy this type error? i can't figure out what it is referring to, as i thought initially it was because the 'ptal' column was a float, so i changed it to be an integer, but it came up with the same error, so it can't be this that the error is referring to.

any suggestions?

```
ptal_lsoas[['ptal']]=ptal_lsoas[['ptal']].astype('float64')
ptal_lsoas.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4835 entries, 0 to 4834
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------      --------------  -----   
 0   geometry    4835 non-null   geometry
 1   lsoa11cd    4835 non-null   object  
 2   avptai2015  4835 non-null   float64 
 3   ptal        4835 non-null   float64 
 4   ptaihigh    4835 non-null   float64 
 5   ptailow     4835 non-null   float64 
dtypes: float64(4), geometry(1), object(1)
memory usage: 264.4+ KB

pr = ps.viz.mapclassify.Quantiles(gdf['ptal'], k=5)
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 12))
gdf.assign(cl_pr=pr.yb).plot(column='cl_pr', categorical=True, k=5, cmap='OrRd', 
                                      linewidth=0.1, ax=ax, edgecolor='white', legend=True)

plt.title('ptal spatial lag')
plt.show()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-185-750b023d96cc> in <module>
----> 1 pr = ps.viz.mapclassify.Quantiles(gdf['ptal'], k=5)
      2 f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20, 12))
      3 gdf.assign(cl_pr=pr.yb).plot(column='cl_pr', categorical=True, k=5, cmap='OrRd', 
      4                                       linewidth=0.1, ax=ax, edgecolor='white', legend=True)
      5 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mapclassify/classifiers.py in __init__(self, y, k)
   1458     def __init__(self, y, k=K):
   1459         self.k = k
-> 1460         MapClassifier.__init__(self, y)
   1461         self.name = "Quantiles"
   1462 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mapclassify/classifiers.py in __init__(self, y)
    615         self.fmt = FMT
    616         self.y = y
--> 617         self._classify()
    618         self._summary()
    619 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mapclassify/classifiers.py in _classify(self)
    634 
    635     def _classify(self):
--> 636         self._set_bins()
    637         self.yb, self.counts = bin1d(self.y, self.bins)
    638 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mapclassify/classifiers.py in _set_bins(self)
   1464         y = self.y
   1465         k = self.k
-> 1466         self.bins = quantile(y, k=k)
   1467 
   1468 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mapclassify/classifiers.py in quantile(y, k)
    232     if p[-1] > 100.0:
    233         p[-1] = 100.0
--> 234     q = np.array([stats.scoreatpercentile(y, pct) for pct in p])
    235     q = np.unique(q)
    236     k_q = len(q)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mapclassify/classifiers.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    232     if p[-1] > 100.0:
    233         p[-1] = 100.0
--> 234     q = np.array([stats.scoreatpercentile(y, pct) for pct in p])
    235     q = np.unique(q)
    236     k_q = len(q)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in scoreatpercentile(a, per, limit, interpolation_method, axis)
   1827         axis = 0
   1828 
-> 1829     return _compute_qth_percentile(sorted_, per, interpolation_method, axis)
   1830 
   1831 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in _compute_qth_percentile(sorted_, per, interpolation_method, axis)
   1871 
   1872     # Use np.add.reduce (== np.sum but a little faster) to coerce data type
-> 1873     return np.add.reduce(sorted_[tuple(indexer)] * weights, axis=axis) / sumval
   1874 
   1875 

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This is kind of error is generated whenever you try to do multiplication of `non-int` type for example, `str` so in this case you have to ensure typecasting of data to `float` before doing the operation.

Comment: yes, thats what i thought, but the only column that isnt a float is the lsoa11cd column, which the code won't let me change to a float?

Comment: What do mean it doesn't allow you to change to float. What type of data is it?
What kind of error did you get when you tried that?

Comment: i've fixed in now, thank you though! i think it was an error in the raw code as when i restarted the raw file and the code it worked :)

Comment: Great! Happy to you..